# Execute multiple dynamic T-SQL statements and obtain a limited number of unique values while preserving order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

I have a `SourceTable` and a table variable `@TQueries` containing various T-SQL predicates that target  `SourceTable`.

The expected result is to dynamically generate `SELECT` statements that return a list of Id's as specified by the predicates in `@TQueries`. Each dynamically generated `SELECT` statement also needs to execute in a particular order, and the final set of values needs to be unique and the ordering must be preserved.

Fortunately, there's a limit to how many values need to be retrieved and how many dynamic queries need to be generated. The Id list should contain at most 10 Ids, and we don't expect more than 7 queries.

**The following is a sample of this setup, not the actual data/database:**

```
-- Set up some test data, this is quick and dirty just to provide some data to test against
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SourceTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    -- Create a numbers table, sorta
    SELECT TOP 20 
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS Id,
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 100 AS [SomeValue]
    INTO [SourceTable]
    FROM sysobjects a
END


DECLARE @TQueries TABLE (
    [Ordinal] INT,
    [WherePredicate] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [OrderByPredicate] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

-- Simulate SELECTs with different order by that get different data due to varying WHERE clauses and ORDER conditions
INSERT INTO @TQueries VALUES ( 1, N'[Id] IN (6,11,13,7,10,3,15)',  '[SomeValue] ASC' ) -- Sort Asc
INSERT INTO @TQueries VALUES ( 2, N'[Id] IN (9,15,14,20,17)', '[SomeValue] DESC' ) -- Sort Desc
INSERT INTO @TQueries VALUES ( 3, N'[Id] IN (20,10,1,16,11,19,9,15,17,6,2,3,13)', 'NEWID()' ) -- Sort Random
```

My main issue has been avoiding the use of a CURSOR or iterating through the rows one by one. The closest I've come to a set operation that meets this criteria is using a table variable to store the results of each query or a massive CTE.

Suggestions and comments are welcome.

Comment: You could use [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx "Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)"). However, the method I have in mind involves adding auxiliary columns to intermediate result sets. When selecting the final result set, you'd have to specify all the columns explicitly to avoid returning those additional columns. Would that be within your requirements?

Comment: Also please note that the order of rows in the output is not guaranteed unless you specify ORDER BY *in the statement that produces the output*.

Comment: @AndriyM, so how could I add an additional column on say the TResults  table variable to ensure the return order follows the insert order?

Comment: I guess you could use a ranking number in this case too, in particular `ROW_NUMBER()`: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS rnk`. Use that when retrieving data from the data table (the target of the stored queries), and then, when displaying the final results, use `rnk` in `ORDER BY` (perhaps with `@TQuery.Original` thrown in there somehow too, not sure).

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  Even ignoring the possibility of latent injection...

Comment: @RBarryYoung, care to expand your comment to something more productive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that builds a single statement both to run all the queries and to return the results.

It uses a similar approach as in your answer when iterating over the `@TQueries` table, i.e. it also uses `{...}` tokens where column values from `@TQuery` should go, and it puts the values there with nested `REPLACE()` calls.

Other than that, it heavily depends on [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx), and I'm not sure if doesn't really *abuse* them. You'd need to test this method before deciding if it's better or worse than the one you've got so far.

```
DECLARE @QueryTemplate nvarchar(max), @FinalSQL nvarchar(max);

SET @QueryTemplate =
N'SELECT
  [Id],
  QueryRank = {Ordinal},
  RowRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {OrderByPredicate})
FROM [dbo].[SourceTable]
WHERE {WherePredicate}
';

SET @FinalSQL =
N'WITH AllData AS (
' +
SUBSTRING(
  (
    SELECT
      'UNION ALL ' +
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@QueryTemplate,
        '{Ordinal}'         , [Ordinal]         ),
        '{OrderByPredicate}', [OrderByPredicate]),
        '{WherePredicate}'  , [WherePredicate]  )
    FROM @TQueries
    ORDER BY [Ordinal]
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
  ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
  11,                      -- starting just after the first 'UNION ALL '
  CAST(0x7FFFFFFF AS int)  -- max int; no need to specify the exact length
) +
'),
RankedData AS (
  SELECT
    [Id],
    QueryRank,
    RowRank,
    ValueRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Id] ORDER BY QueryRank)
  FROM AllData
)SELECT TOP (@top)
  [Id]
FROM RankedData
WHERE ValueRank = 1
ORDER BY
  QueryRank,
  RowRank
';

PRINT @FinalSQL;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @FinalSQL, N'@top int', 10;
```

Basically, every subquery gets these auxiliary columns:

- `QueryRank` – a constant value (within the subquery's result set) derived from `[Ordinal]`;
- `RowRank` – a ranking assigned to a row based on the `[OrderByPredicate]`.

The result sets are UNIONed and then every entry of every unique value is again ranked (`ValueRank`) based on the query ranking.

When pulling the final result set, duplicates are suppressed (by the condition `ValueRank = 1`), and `QueryRank` and `RowRank` are used in the `ORDER BY` clause to preserve the original row order.

I used `EXECUTE sp_executesql @query` instead of `EXECUTE (@query)`, because the former allows you to add parameters to the query. In particular, I parametrised the number of results to return (the argument of `TOP`). But you could certainly concatenate that value into the dynamic script directly, just like other things, if you prefer `EXECUTE ()` over `EXECUTE sq_executesql`.

If you like, you can try this query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e106/2). (Note: the SQL Fiddle version replaces the `@TQueries` table variable with the `TQueries` table.)

Comment: Thanks, I really liked this approach and I didn't know about the SQL Fiddle site!

However, against the actual database the other method seems to perform a bit better, due to having a bunch of left outer joins which SQL Server 2005 optimizes away, but not in the CTE version. But this version is more compact and the performance difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've managed to piece together cobbled from my original response and improved upon by comments from @AndriyM

```
DECLARE @sql_prefix NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql_prefix = 
N'DECLARE @TResults TABLE (
    [Ordinal] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ContentItemId] INT
);

DECLARE @max INT, @top INT;
SELECT @max = 10;';


DECLARE @sql_insert_template NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql_body NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql_insert_template = 
N'SELECT @top = @max - COUNT(*) FROM @TResults; 
INSERT INTO @TResults
SELECT TOP (@top) [Id] 
FROM [dbo].[SourceTable] 
WHERE 
    {WherePredicate} 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM @TResults AS [tr] 
        WHERE [tr].[ContentItemId] = [SourceTable].[Id]
    )
ORDER BY {OrderByPredicate};';

    WITH Query ([Ordinal],[SqlCommand]) AS (
        SELECT 
            [Ordinal],
            REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql_insert_template, '{WherePredicate}', [WherePredicate]), '{OrderByPredicate}', [OrderByPredicate])
        FROM @TQueries
    )
    SELECT 
        @sql_body = @sql_prefix + (
            SELECT [SqlCommand]
            FROM Query
            ORDER BY [Ordinal] ASC
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)') + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
            +N' SELECT * FROM @TResults ORDER BY [Ordinal]';

    EXEC(@sql_body);
```

The basic idea is to use a table variable to hold the results of each query. I create a template for the SQL and replace the values in the template based on what is stored in `@TQueries`.

Once the entire script is completed I run it with EXEC.

Comment: Your answer has helped me to understand some aspects of the problem better. Particularly I was confused about the fact that in @TQuery, a query seemed to be stored in its entirety and it was unclear how you were going to extract bits like ORDER BY and, possibly, others. But I can see now that either that was just an illustration or that particular part of the design was (and may still be) in development. Anyway, like I said, this answer clears up things for me, and, when I have a minute, I hope to try and come up with an implementation of the idea I mentioned earlier. And good job on this one!

Comment: Ah, but you cheated! You changed the question as well (just noticed that). :) Still, I like the answer never the less.

Comment: @Andriy M, I know, it wasn't intentional, but when planting the question I had abstracted out parts of the problem. Then while working with it I noticed having the entire query was not beneficial and I was building the query from scratch anyways. 

Point being, I didn't want to make the question too comlicated.

Comment: @Andriy M, and yes, you were quite right, having the whole query stored wasn't beneficial. There is a point in the process where I take the different bits and make it into a whole query, and I thought for this question's purpose splitting off at that point was good, but later on it seemed more of a hindrance